# Insiro um valor num div e ele se desloca

Tags: javascript, css

Olá,
Tenho este esta folha de estilos:

```
   #contentor {
        width:315px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

     div.linha div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size:32px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

E este script:

```
    var corFundo = "red";

    function mudarFundo00() {
        c00.style.backgroundColor = corFundo;
        corFundo = "yellow";
        c00.innerHTML = "X";
    }


    var c00 = document.getElementById('c00');
    c00.addEventListener('click', mudarFundo00);
```

Antes de clicar tenho isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clico obtenho isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém me pode explicar a razão desse deslocamento e como deixar o div
na posição inicial?

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

para resolver você só precisa colocar a propriedade "vertical-align:top" em "div.linha div {" para as div se alinharem.

```css
<style>
  #contentor {
   width:315px;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
 
   div.linha div {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size:32px;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 100px;
   vertical-align:top;
  }
 
  h1 {
   text-align: center;
  }
 </style>
```

```html
<div id="contentor">
     <div class="linha">
         <div id="c00"></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
  var corFundo = "red";

  function mudarFundo00() {
   c00.style.backgroundColor = corFundo;
   corFundo = "yellow";
   c00.innerHTML = "X";
  }
 
 
  var c00 = document.getElementById('c00');
  c00.addEventListener('click', mudarFundo00);
    
    c00.click();
 </script>
```

Comment: Valeu matmartino! É isso mesmo. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Olá, seja bem-vindo ao SOpt, o problema está basicamente seu line-height, quando você colocou o elemento X, ele desalinhou... o valor correto seria: `line-height: 182px;`para não desalinhar mas daí seu x, não iria ficar centralizado, a solucão neste caso, seria fazer o seguinte:

```
div.linha div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size:32px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 105px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

[**Fiddle de exemplo**](https://jsfiddle.net/wtc0bzpg/).

Comment: Valeu Ivan! Muito obrigado pelo tempo dispendido em me ajudar. Comunidade fantástica!